# Using Node request - How to authenticate on challenge based web page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, node-modules

Exploring the ['request'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package to perform some automated tasks at the office.

The requirement is to automatically log into a server (but there are many many), navigate to a web page and then collect information then create a report with it.

Thing is, these servers first ask for a user account, then they generate a challenge number that one would copy and paste into another server to be resolved as the challenge response. This response is pasted back into the web page I want the script to log in.

Trying to figure out how to go about doing this with 'request'. Following code only gets as far as looping through the page where to enter the user name:

```
"use strict"
var request = require('request');

var getJar = request.jar();
var opts = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://serverIP/path/to/post/action',
    agentOptions: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    jar: getJar,
    followAllRedirects: true
};

var postJar = request.jar();
var postOpts = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://serverIP/path/to/post/action',
    form: {
        userName: 'init'
    },
    agentOptions: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    postJar: postJar,
    followAllRedirects: true,
    headers: {
        'Referer': 'value I see in dev console'
    }
};

request(opts, function (err, res, body) {

    console.log('GET error is: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    console.log('GET response is: ' + res);
    console.log('GET body is: ' + body);

    var cookie_string = getJar.getCookieString(opts.uri);
    var cookies = getJar.getCookies(opts.uri);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cookies) + '\n' + cookie_string);

    postOpts.postJar.setCookie(cookie_string, postOpts.uri);

    request(postOpts, function (err, res, body) {
        console.log('POST error is: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        console.log('POST response is: ' + res);
        console.log('POST body is: ' + body);

    });
});
```

The form parameters in the snippet are things I see in Firefox's developer console under Network > POST request > Params when I submit the user name through the browser.

The code is only taking me back to the page where the user name is requested. It kind of gets stuck there. I know this by logging the value of the POST body to console, it spits out the HTML code asking for that value, instead of the HTML where you see the challenge string and the input field where to paste the challenge response.

What may I do differently?

Answer (score 0):

I used 'request-debug' package for further insight. Turned out, the first GET request happened successfully, from which I take the cookie=sessionId value, and inject it into the POST message jar as shown in my initial snippet.

With the debug on, I was able to detect a redirection to a URL saying 'cookiesRequired' at the end, request was following this redirection and generating a second GET to it, where I was shown HTML code with the message 'Invalid session you must be logged in'.

It then hit me that, the cookie-session system was not working properly. I saw from the second GET that it inserted a **header** with the session id taken from the cookie. So I injected this header into postJar like this:

```
var cookie_string = getJar.getCookieString(opts.uri);   
console.log('ATTENTION--- The cookie from getJar is:\t' + cookie_string);

postOpts.headers.cookie = cookie_string;
```

This line doesnt even affect the behavior so far:

```
    postOpts.jar.setCookie(cookie_string, '/');
```

After inserting the cookie header I am now getting prompted to resolve the next phase of the authentication.